# Get the instance type of a singleton class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a singleton class:

```
class Singleton {
  private static instance: Singleton;

  private constructor() {
    // Private constructor to prevent instantiation outside the class
  }

  public static getInstance(): Singleton {
    if (!Singleton.instance) {
      Singleton.instance = new Singleton();
    }
    return Singleton.instance;
  }

  someMethod(): void {
    console.log("Singleton method called");
  }
}
```

I know there is a type `InstanceType`, but it doesn't work with private constructors.

```
// Cannot assign a 'private' constructor type to a 'public' constructor type
type SingletonType = InstanceType<typeof Singleton>;
```

Is it possible to create a custom type that returns instance type of classes with private constructors?

---

### **EDIT**

Well, I'll try to shed some light on the whole situation. I hope this clears up misunderstandings. As I wrote earlier I have a singleton class with a `private` constructor. I have to pass this singleton to constructor of another generic class as a parameter:

```
class BaseEntity<T extends typeof Singleton = typeof Singleton> {
    private singletonInstance: InstanceType<T>;
    
    constructor(instance: InstanceType<T>) {        
        this.singletonInstance = instance;        
    }
}
```

As far as `Singleton` class has a `private` constructor, I get an error `Cannot assign a 'private' constructor type to a 'public' constructor type` when trying to get its instance `InstanceType<T>`. So my question is, is it possible to create a custom generic type that accepts classes with "private" constructors and returns an instance type similar to "InstanceType"?

Comment: You might want to [edit] to clarify that you apparently only have access to the constructor `typeof Singleton` and not to the class instance type `Singleton`.  I had to read this five times before I realized that you weren't just confused and asking for `type SingletonType = Singleton`.  Does `type SingletonType = typeof Singleton.prototype;` meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Unclear what you ask

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76392242/get-the-instance-type-of-a-singleton-class-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment134707303_76392242) @jcalz I'm pretty sure [that comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76392242/get-the-instance-type-of-a-singleton-class-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment134707242_76392242) was aimed at the question asker. 

Comment: Oh yes, definitely - sorry for the ambiguity ! I mean that the original post is unclear ...

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76392242/get-the-instance-type-of-a-singleton-class-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment134707552_76392242) @jcalz No, I don’t think it’s subpar — it took me a few reads as well to arrive at the same conclusion… although I suspect they might simply be unaware that the class name identifier is also available as a type representing an instance of the class — I think this is a duplicate, but hopefully they can clarify.

Comment: @jcalz, I updated my question. Please review it again. Thanks

Comment: @Nolesh Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJx6DN) refactor work? If not, please update the question to clarify why not.

Comment: @Nolesh, that makes it unfortunately *less* clear for me.  I suggested you use the `prototype` property, did you try that?  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wj837m) with your new code.  But I don't understand why you want `typeof Singleton` at all; the example code could work even better with the instancetype to begin with, like `T extends Singleton` as in jsejcksn shows.  How should we proceed here?

Comment: @jsejcksn, I need to use `typeof Singleton` to get rid of a `circular default` in Singleton class (I omitted some details in my question to keep it simple).  In fact, my Singleton class is generic class `class Singleton<T extends BaseEntity = BaseEntity>`.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76392242/get-the-instance-type-of-a-singleton-class-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment134708033_76392242) @Nolesh Please carefully review how to create a [mre] and update the question accordingly so that the **actual** constraints and requirements are present in full detail; currently, the question is unclear. Consider also including a link to the code in the [TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/we82gW) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: @jsejcksn, ok. I think `jcalz` has answered my question.

Comment: @jcalz, I misunderstood you and misused "prototype". Now `T["prototype"]` works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript assumes that class constructors have a `prototype` property whose type is the same as the class instance type.  This isn't actually true in practice, since generally speaking [class fields](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#fields) won't actually be present on the `prototype`.  But TypeScript makes that assumption as an approximation intentionally, and has declined suggestions to change this (see [microsoft/TypeScript#11558](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11558) and [microsoft/TypeScript#20922](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20922) for examples).

And so, if [the `InstanceType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) is unavailable to you because of a [`private`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#private) constructor, you can get the same information by [indexing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into the constructor's type with `"prototype"`:

```
type AlsoInstanceType<T extends { prototype: any }> =
  T["prototype"];

type SingletonType = AlsoInstanceType<typeof Singleton>
// type SingletonType = Singleton

class Foo { a = 1 }
type Example = AlsoInstanceType<typeof Foo>
// type Example = Foo;
```

And thus your `BaseEntity` can be written that way:

```
class BaseEntity<T extends typeof Singleton = typeof Singleton> {
  private singletonInstance: AlsoInstanceType<T>;

  constructor(instance: AlsoInstanceType<T>) {
    this.singletonInstance = instance;
  }
}
```

---

For `Singleton` in *particular* you could write `ReturnType<typeof Singleton.getInstance>` using [the `ReturnType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype):

```
type AlsoSingletonType = ReturnType<typeof Singleton.getInstance>;
// type AlsoSingletonType = Singleton

type SingletonInstance<T extends typeof Singleton> = ReturnType<T["getInstance"]>;
type AlsoAlsoSingletonType = SingletonInstance<typeof Singleton>;
// type AlsoAlsoSingletonType = Singleton
```

But `T["prototype"]` is more flexible.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCWA7A5iApgFwPaOgbwChpoAHAJ3gDcwM1oIMb5hokGxFg0AuOJVTDgDcBIqQrVa0YDgZkArsGxkAFAEp8Y4gHpt0AAoSadGYjmLl0bOLSU0iDKzOMH8JjmhZ5GCPAAmdBgAFibgUGIAvqLEJPIARiDM9IwYSciYAJLOHFzqvAgo6Ni4hMTE8ABm0CoAhAUCxQB0bC5cGqVlxPVFOM3ZnHQAvNCIaADufIWCiOoinVGdZJjyZLjd033sA3PQUWIQWAC2aACymEFYfnnQlFj+mp2mB+iNIFjIKgBE68XQx8GXaRgEDoPyfNQ7KJ7DAATxIdAAgiADlktlwACpwtAAHnR0DQAA9aIg-DA8OIsNhYfDeBwYbsAHzQQZidEAbU+5EplKxnwAuiICNS6D8cJj4czoEiUf0MVjscKsFVRYgGQRdFYsZMGmKtcMVaJQJAYAAxLBYfDQMCSgCMuyFWoAogSwIcSOhJdKsKjWmhxTjFVUzVg1RrhdBna73UNoMHBUaoNAAEKQNCO1yw3H4on2Uma+FK7U9XDDQNF6ZMjrkKjGej8Ys+nI8KXI72yv3y9EMwXEJ4YBRKLCqFpN3hexsDf24hntLRWILwCCNXxTYoTriSkfbSIEaFar0q-2SgBKy1WU7LKsa6Qw67Q3fVenDB-r0yP+tfxVE4ZVd6zhOJPNL0-HAmWGU8MBWRAp3ZT4bzvfkH2fVsX1XXUJQ-NDED-YCsIfMN9xQ1tDz1ctiiAA)